# problem with calculating overtime pay on python

Tags: python

I am a new python user. I have an issue with the code I am writing. I am supposed to
make a weekly pay check program that calculates how much you'll get paid. I also have to account for overtime hours.

*This was the instructions given to my teacher* -

---

> The first 40 hours you work, you get paid your regular hourly wage.
> The next 10 hours are overtime and paid to you at 1.5 times your
> hourly rate. The rest of your hours (greater than 50) is paid to you
> at twice your hourly rate.

**This is the code I've made for it:**

---

```
def weeklypaycheck(hours,rate):
    if (hours <= 40):
        pay = hours * rate
        print("This is your pay: ",pay)
    elif hours > 40 or hours < 50:
        nm = 40 * rate
        othours = hours - 40
        otpay = (othours * (rate * 1.5))
        print("This is your pay: ", otpay + nm)
    elif hours > 50:
        nm = 40 * rate
        otpay = (10 * (rate * 1.5))
        othours = hours - 50
        otpay = (othours2 * (rate *2))
        print("This is your pay: ", nm+ otpay + otpay)
```

So when I'm in the shell window and run it.
I input: `weeklypaycheck(55,10)`

> ps. '55' is the total hours worked, '10' is how much I get paid per hour

And this is my output: `This is your pay: 625.0`

My output is supposed to be `This is your pay: 650.0` and not `This is your pay: 625.0`.

Same goes if input `weeklypaycheck(51,20)`
I'll output `This is your pay 1130.0`

My output is supposed to be `This is your pay: 1140` and not `This is your pay: 1140`.

My math might be off but I'm very confused. If anyone is willing to help me, thank you!

Comment: You can refactor the code a bit for clarity.  You have the same base pay calculation in each branch.  The last two branches have the same overtime calculation (or should). Also there is a bug for hours == 50 which doesn't match anything.  You have 3 branches of your conditional but only  two boundaries so the last statement could be an else.  You have the same (if you refactor it)  print statement in each branch so isn't conditional.

Answer (score 3):

You wrote: `if hours > 40 or hours < 50`.  Ask yourself very carefully what hours satisfy this if.  For example, does 60 hours satisfy this?  What about 30 hours?

Answer (score 0):

I refactored the code as suggested above to eliminate the duplicate code, used `else` instead of `elif` when it made sense, fixed defect for `hours == 50`, and introduced a dict `h` to logical group the hours break-down:

```
def weeklypaycheck(hours, rate):
    h = {'regular': 0, 'overtime': 0, 'extra': 0}
    if hours <= 40:
        h['regular'] = hours
    else:
        h['regular'] = 40
        if hours <= 50:
            h['overtime'] = hours - 40
        else:
            h['overtime'] = 10
            h['extra'] = hours - 50
    pay = h['regular'] * rate +\
        h['overtime'] * 1.5 * rate +\
        h['extra'] * 2 * rate
    print(f"This is your pay: {pay}")
```

There is a different way of thinking about this problem, namely, what the min or max hours for each hours break-down.  This yield this implementation (notice that only hours break-down calculation changed):

```
def weeklypaycheck(hours, rate):
    h = {
            'regular': min(hours, 40),
            'overtime': max(min(hours - 40, 10), 0),
            'extra': max(hours - 50, 0)
    }
    pay = h['regular'] * rate +\
        h['overtime'] * 1.5 * rate +\
        h['extra'] * 2 * rate
    print(f"This is your pay: {pay}")
```

and I would test the boundary conditions like this:

```
for hours in [39, 40, 41, 49, 50, 51]:
    weeklypaycheck(hours, 1)
```

and the results are:

```
This is your pay: 39.0
This is your pay: 40.0
This is your pay: 41.5
This is your pay: 53.5
This is your pay: 55.0
This is your pay: 57.0
```